# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Check if product is monthly or yearly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I made my own price tables where I have to check now if the product is a monthly or yearly subscription project. I want to make this as easy as possible because I think this should work with an easy if sentence.

Now I am using this to find out if the product has a price or not.

```
if($product->price)...
```

I hope that such a thing is also possible for a subscription, but I can't find something in the docs. Would be very nice if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `$product->subscription_period` property, is it `'month'` or `'year'` for WooCommerce Subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for your reply! So the code should be like: if($product->subscription_period == 'month')...

Comment: Yes, if `$product` is a 'Subscription' it has a property `subscription_period`, and in your case you can check `if($product->subscription_period == 'month')` or `if($product->subscription_period == 'year')`.